# Generating random number sequences & sorting them out in java

Tags: java, arrays

Good day,

I am currently working on this program, which has to generate as many numbers as I enter (between 1-100) and the number has to be in the range of 0 - 1 000 000.

Then, the program must print them out in a random order and after that using the insertion sort, it must sort the randomly generated numbers.

I've been tackling this for about 7 hours now, searched online for answers, but haven't found anything yet. I was hoping to get a fix for my problem here!

**What the program is supposed to do:**

1. Person enters how many random numbers they want the program to generate (between 1-100)
2. Print out the amount of random numbers (random numbers must must be in the range of 0 - 1 000 000), the person entered before.
3. Sort the numbers using insertion sorting and print them out.

**This is what I currently have:**

*It doesn't print out the sorted list.*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the amount:");
    int amount = scan.nextInt();
    int []numbers = new int[amount];

    Random rand = new Random();
    System.out.println("Random order:");
    int MAX = 1000000;
    int MIN = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("From smallest to biggest:");

    sort(numbers);


}
        public static int[] sort(int[] list) {
            int i, j, key, temp;
            for(i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
                key = list[i];
                j = i-1;

                while (j >= 0 && list[j] > key) {
                    temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j+1];
                    list[j+1] = temp;
                    j--;
                }

                System.out.print(list);
            }



            return list;
        }
```

}

Comment: Did you try invoking the `sort` method?

Comment: @AndyTurner I haven't actually, because I'm brand new to this sorting thing and have no idea how to do it :/ Sorry if the answer is obvious, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You've written a `sort` method, you never call it. How do you think your array will be sorted otherwise?

Comment: You know how to call `nextInt` and `println`.  Calling your own method is even simpler, since you don't even have to pre-fix it with the object name, as you've defined it as a static method and it is in the same class as the main method.

Comment: @DavidChoweller I called the method, but still it doesn't sort the array and print it out.. :/

Comment: Update your question to show how you are calling your method.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Did it.

Comment: First, you should  print the array in your main program. Second, right now your printing is happening before the array fully sorted.  Third, you cannot just print the array by passing the whole thing to `System.print`.  You need to do it in a loop, running from the starting index of the array to the last index and calling `System.print` on each array element.

Comment: Actually,  you are already printing the array in the main program before it is sorted.   Just do the same thing after it is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I think u forgot to call the sort method.

Comment: I'm really sorry, if this question comes off as very stupid, but how exactly do I do that?

Comment: You don't know how to call a method but you know how to write sorting method.Its very strange

Comment: The thing is, when calling the method, it still doesn't work properly. It doesn't print out the array in a sorted order.